# How to install KeePass on Mac OS X Mountain Lion

Tags: macos, osx-mountain-lion, keepass, mono-framework

I'm using KeePass on Windows. It's a very nice application. Now I want to run it on my Mac. The instructions on the download page are too techy and I don't have prior experience with Macs.

How can I install KeePass on OS X, then?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's really simple:

- Download the current version from [here](http://keepass.info/download.html)
- You get KeePass2.2x.x.pkg file - double-ckick this file to start the Installer
- Confirm the License and the default destination
- You are ready: find kindly the KeePass App in "Applications" folder!

> The problems reported on the KeePass forum have been resolved, we have
>   reworked the installation process, **KeePass installation is now done by
>   an installer, which should make the installation easier**.  We are
>   working on further integration with OS X native Cocoa interface, and
>   bundling it with Mono so that **a separate Mono download is no longer
>   needed** ...

Comment: Is there any plans to make it available via the App Store? Also, will I be able to open my `2.X` database that I created in windows in this version?

Comment: Sorry, I don't know it ...

Comment: You could try KyPass companion, which you can get from the App Store.

Comment: this answer is now outdated, http://keepass2.openix.be does not exist

Comment: @duDE I don't see the `.pkg` file on the download site. Was it removed?

Answer (score 9):

I have used KeePassX Alpha Release mentioned in previous posts, but have found [MacPass](https://github.com/mstarke/MacPass) to be a great alternative. It feels more like a native OSX app, attempting to create a native OS X port of KeePass. It [can Open/Save some Kdbx and Kdb databases](https://github.com/mstarke/MacPass/wiki/Status):

> - <s>Save and load unprotected databases (no password, no key file)</s> Removed!
> - Load database with only keyfile, key and password, only password.
> - Support keyfile formats. (KeePass 2 XML, KeePass 1 binary, arbitrary)
> - Export as Keepass XML
> - <s>Import from Keepass XML</s>
> - Save KDB as KDBX
> - Save KDBX as KDB

https://github.com/mstarke/MacPass

> System Requirement
>
> The minimum OS X version required for MacPass is currently 10.8 Mountain Lion.

Answer (score 3):

I have tried to use Keepass on OSX, but it doesn't work very well; it is slow as hell and crashes all the time. I ended up getting [KyPass Companion](http://www.kyuran.be/logiciels/kypass4mac/) from the AppStore. It works very well and supports both Keepass 1 and 2 databases.

The downside of KyPass for some people might be that it's not free.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post.

Comment: @Sekhemty I think this is a good answer for many people as getting Keepass to work on OSX might be pretty hard. So, I'm just offering an option here. It's easier to find a solotion as an answer than as a comment to the original post.

Answer (score 2):

I'm using KeePassX from [http://www.keepassx.org/downloads/](http://www.keepassx.org/downloads) .
The performance is quite good except it does not support auto-type into application.

Comment: It doesn't support KDBX (Keepass 2) format.

Comment: KeePassX v2 alpha releases support Keepass2 formats.

Answer (score 2):

Use alpha release 5:

https://www.keepassx.org/news/2013/12/420

It works great with both the key file and password. Very cool.

Comment: Alpha release 6 is out. Thanks for letting us know!